# Remove file without case sensivity

Tags: linux, bash, file, function

I have got the following bash function:

```
function tpc()
{
    cp $1 .dosbox/TP/BIN/
    dosbox -c "TPC.EXE $1"
    rm .dosbox/TP/BIN/$1
    #rm .dosbox/TP/BIN/$(basename $1 .pas).EXE
}
```

The main purpose is:

tpc "file.pas"

then it compiles on "dosbox", removes the "file.pas" in the `.dosbox` path. But I want to do something else: "remove the .exe file". The problem is the following if I do: `tpc file.pas` turbo pascal compiles `FILE.EXE`, then `.dosbox/TP/BIN/$(basename $1 .pas).EXE` is trying to remove "file.EXE". The question is: "how to remove the uppercase `.exe` file?

Comment: `find . -iname $(basename $1 .pas).EXE -delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could do this:

```
function tpc()
{
    cp "$1" .dosbox/TP/BIN/
    dosbox -c "TPC.EXE $1"
    rm ".dosbox/TP/BIN/$1"
    REMOVE=${1^^} REMOVE=${REMOVE##*/} REMOVE=${REMOVE%.???}.EXE
    rm ".dosbox/TP/BIN/$REMOVE"
}
```

For more info about the methods used, please see [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: This is the elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `find` command has an `iname` switch that makes the search case insensitive.

```
find . -iname $(basename $1 .pas).EXE -delete
```

It has also the `delete` switch, to remove the files found. If you want to restrict the search to files under a specific directory, replace the `.` with the directory path.

Comment: That could take a very long time if you have a deep directory tree structure.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Bash documentation on `shopt` [1](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Probably the thing You'd like to do is something like that:

```
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
rm .dosbox/TP/BIN/$(basename $1 .pas).EX
shopt -u nocaseglob
```